# Isotope won't reload onkeypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

When i'm using onkeypress the isotope('reloadItems') won't reload the layout which means the textarea gets pushed under the item below. Can anyone help please? :] [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLo0gojb/)

```
<script src='assets/scripts/textareagrow.js'></script>
<script src='assets/scripts/isotope.js'></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    $('.trans_comment').css('overflow', 'hidden').autogrow();

    $('.main_trans_contain').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });

});
</script>



<div class='main_trans_contain'>

    <div class='item' style='width: 300px;margin: 10px;'>

        <textarea onkeypress="$('.main_trans_contain').isotope('reloadItems');" class='trans_comment'></textarea>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What about `$('#yourTextarea').on('input', function() {$('.main_trans_contain').isotope('reloadItems');});`

Comment: Did you change the selector `$('#yourTextarea')` and/or add an id to your texterea. You can do just `$('textarea')` for a testing purpose and change it after. Plus, "it don't work" should never be and answer here.

Comment: yep, i've done that and nothing :/ I know isotope is working because it reloads when I resize my window

Comment: Do you know if the event is fired on your textarea? `$('#yourTextarea').on('input', function() {console.warn('Hey')})` `$('#yourTextarea').on('keyup', function() {console.warn('Hey')})` `$('#yourTextarea').on('keyprss', function() {console.warn('Hey')})`

Comment: I set up a jsfiddle for you :] [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rLo0gojb/)

Answer (score 0):

Use 'layout" instead of 'reloadItems'
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/rLo0gojb/1/)

```
$(function() {

$('.trans_comment').css('overflow', 'hidden').autogrow();

$('.main_trans_contain').isotope({
itemSelector: '.item'
});


$('.trans_comment').on('input', function(){
$('.main_trans_contain').isotope('layout');
});


});
```